# Remove asp.net button handler using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using Jquery to hide and show the buttons(Add,Edit,Delete) which is not secure. Can i remove the handler when hiding the buttons & add it when showing. Can it be acheived using Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent postback on button click using javascript. But you can't affect server-side event subscription from client code. All the way you need to have server-side security check.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood your question well. If it's a security concern wouldn't it be better to implement the logic server side?